# Metropolis-specific TypeError: The broadcastable pattern of the input is incorrect for this op

Tags: python, theano, tensor, pymc3, hierarchical-bayesian

I am trying to build a multilevel, multidimensional Bayesian model in PyMC3.  For this question, I'll use a smaller toy model with the following graph structure:
[image: Graphical model of transcript capture efficiency]

where `G` represents genes, `K` cell types, and `C_k` cells of cell type `k`.  Overall the model represents gene transcripts being sampled from a collection of cells of different cell types, where there is some binomial distribution parameterized by cell type mean expression level, `mu_gk`, and a cell-specific capture efficiency, `p_kc`.

When I sample this toy model with NUTS, it does fine and recovers reasonable posterior distributions:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt


# Generative model for data simulation
def sample_data(G=1, K=2, C_k=100):
    mu_gk = np.random.randint(1, 1000, size=(G, K))
    p_kc = np.random.beta(5, 95, (K, C_k))
    N_gkc = np.random.binomial(mu_gk[:, :, np.newaxis], p_kc[np.newaxis, :, :])

    return N_gkc


G = 10    # genes
K = 5     # cell types
C_k = 20  # cells per type

data = sample_data(G, K, C_k)

with pm.Model() as capture_efficiency:

    # Genes expression levels per cell type
    mu_gk = pm.Uniform('mu_gk', 1, 1000, shape=(G, K, 1))

    # Cell capture efficiencies
    p_kc = pm.Beta('p_kc', shape=(1, K, C_k), alpha=5, beta=95)

    # Captured transcripts
    N_gkc = pm.Binomial('N_gkc', shape=(G, K, C_k),
                        n=tt.tensordot(mu_gk, np.ones((C_k, 1)), [[2], [1]]),
                        p=tt.tensordot(np.ones((G, 1)), p_kc, [[1], [0]]),
                        observed=data)

    trace = pm.sample(5000, tune=10000, target_accept=0.99)
```

However, when I attempt to sample with Metropolis, e.g.,

```
    trace = pm.sample(5000, tune=10000, step=pm.Metropolis())
```

I receive the following stack trace and error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 52, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/mfansler/Projects/pymc3/intro/capture-efficiency-celltypes.py", line 46, in <module>
    trace = pm.sample(5000, tune=10000,  step=pm.Metropolis(),
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/step_methods/arraystep.py", line 65, in __new__
    step.__init__([var], *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/step_methods/metropolis.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.delta_logp = delta_logp(model.logpt, vars, shared)
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/step_methods/metropolis.py", line 624, in delta_logp
    [logp0], inarray0 = pm.join_nonshared_inputs([logp], vars, shared)
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/theanof.py", line 245, in join_nonshared_inputs
    xs_special = [theano.clone(x, replace, strict=False) for x in xs]
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/theanof.py", line 245, in <listcomp>
    xs_special = [theano.clone(x, replace, strict=False) for x in xs]
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_utils.py", line 247, in clone
    share_inputs)
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 232, in rebuild_collect_shared
    cloned_v = clone_v_get_shared_updates(outputs, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 93, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    clone_v_get_shared_updates(i, copy_inputs_over)
  [Previous line repeated 9 more times]
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 96, in clone_v_get_shared_updates
    [clone_d[i] for i in owner.inputs], strict=rebuild_strict)
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/graph.py", line 246, in clone_with_new_inputs
    new_node = self.op.make_node(*new_inputs)
  File "/Users/mfansler/anaconda/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/tensor/elemwise.py", line 230, in make_node
    % (self.input_broadcastable, ib)))
TypeError: The broadcastable pattern of the input is incorrect for this op. Expected (False, False, True), got (False, False, False).
```

I did find [a GitHub issue filed for something along these lines](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/1983), but I'm unclear on how the "workaround" someone proposed for their specific model would translate in my case.

I suspect the most relevant aspect of this model to the error encountered is the manual broadcasting of the parameters when instantiating the Binomial random variable:

```
n=tt.tensordot(mu_gk, np.ones((C_k, 1)), [[2], [1]]),
p=tt.tensordot(np.ones((G, 1)), p_kc, [[1], [0]])
```

which "extrudes" the 2D tensors into 3D ones matching the desired output shape.

How should this model be implemented in order to avoid the error when running Metropolis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making all parameter sampling steps flat appears to be sufficient for this toy model:

```
with pm.Model() as capture_efficiency:

    # Genes expression levels per cell type
    mu_gk_flat = pm.Uniform('mu_gk', 1, 1000, shape=G*K)
    mu_gk = mu_gk_flat.reshape((G, K, 1))

    # Cell capture efficiencies
    p_kc_flat = pm.Beta('p_kc', shape=K*C_k, alpha=5, beta=95)
    p_kc = p_kc_flat.reshape((1, K, C_k))

    # Captured transcripts
    N_gkc = pm.Binomial('N_gkc', shape=(G, K, C_k),
                        n=tt.tensordot(mu_gk, np.ones((C_k, 1)), [[2], [1]]),
                        p=tt.tensordot(np.ones((G, 1)), p_kc, [[1], [0]]),
                        observed=data)

    trace = pm.sample(5000, tune=10000, step=pm.Metropolis())
```

The `N_gkc` seems to be fine in tensor form, perhaps because it merely involves a likelihood calculation and not an actual sampling step.

From this toy example alone, it is not clear if additional hierarchical levels would also need to be flattened.